# 404 with http.FileServer with absolute path

Tags: go, server, http-status-code-404, fileserver

I have a file `C:\hello\index.go`:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   http.Handle("/assets", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets")))
   println("ListenAndServe")
   http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

I enter `go run index.go`, then make this request:

```
PS C:\> curl localhost:9000/assets/kitten.jpg
404 page not found
```

I know the path is valid:

```
PS C:\> curl -I file:/C:/hello/assets/kitten.jpg
Content-Length: 3000898
Accept-ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Sun, 16 Jan 2022 01:14:58 GMT
```

I also tried these other lines:

```
http.Handle("/assets", http.FileServer(http.Dir(`C:\hello\assets`)))
http.Handle("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets")))
http.Handle("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(`C:\hello\assets`)))
```

but I get 404 every time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use the [`http.StripPrefix`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#StripPrefix) function.

Example similar to yours. Please note the trailing `/` I've added:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))))
    println("ListenAndServe")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

Example from the docs:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // To serve a directory on disk (/tmp) under an alternate URL
    // path (/tmpfiles/), use StripPrefix to modify the request
    // URL's path before the FileServer sees it:
    http.Handle("/tmpfiles/", http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This command:

```golang
http.Handle("/assets", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets")))
```

Sets the filesystem root to `assets`, then the request is added on top of that.
So if you make a request like this:

```
/assets/kitten.jpg
```

Then the server will look for a path like this:

```
assets/assets/kitten.jpg
```

I have seen some people suggest using `StripPrefix`, but this seems to do the
job as well:

```
http.Handle("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
```